# How to change a specific row value if the data frame have "Day 1, Day 2... etc" in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How to change a specific row value if the data frame have "Day 1, Day 2... etc" as a column value(without hardcoding of any column name or row name) in R and remove the entire row of that value.

**DATA:**

```
library(tidyverse)

emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:5), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
   Start_Day = (c("1", "2", "3", "Day 15",
                         "7")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
# Print the data frame.         
print(emp.data)
```

**output:**

```
emp_id    emp_name       Start_Day
1      1     Rick          1
2      2      Dan          2
3      3   Michelle        3
4      4     Ryan       Day 15
5      5     Gary          7
```

**Expected output:**

```
emp_id    emp_name       Day 15
1      1     Rick          1
2      2      Dan          2
3      3   Michelle        3
4      5     Gary          7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for data in a particular column you can use :

```
result <- subset(emp.data, !grepl('Day \\d+', Start_Day))
names(result)[3] <- grep('Day \\d+', emp.data$Start_Day, value = TRUE)
result

#  emp_id emp_name Day 15
#1      1     Rick      1
#2      2      Dan      2
#3      3 Michelle      3
#5      5     Gary      7
```

If you want to do this in entire dataframe without hardcoding any column name :

```
result <- subset(emp.data,!Reduce(`|`, lapply(emp.data, function(x) grepl('Day \\d+', x))))
names(result)[3] <- grep('Day \\d+', as.matrix(emp.data), value = TRUE)
```

and with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

emp.data %>% filter(across(everything(), ~!str_detect(., 'Day \\d+')))
```

Comment: How to replace the same value (example : Day 15) to the column name as per the expected output (without hardcoding the column name)

Comment: How to remove only Day 15( day 1, day 2, etc..) not the entire row value, and make the same value to the same column name without hardcoding

Comment: `emp.data[sapply(emp.data, function(x) grepl('Day \\d+', x))] <- NA`

Comment: I am not sure then. Can you ask that as a new question?

Comment: But it still does not change the row value day 15(( day 1, day 2, etc..) to column Value

Comment: The previous code would remain the same to rename the column name. `names(result)[3] <- grep('Day \\d+', as.matrix(emp.data), value = TRUE)`

Comment: Shak, here "names(result)[3]" the column 3 is hardcoded, it would be helpful without its hardcoded